# How do I create a UNION query that will return the latest date an item was inventoried?

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables as pictured below and would like a union query to combine them, but only return the latest date of any item. 
[image: Tables and results]

Comment: We don't do your coding on Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? PS if the picture represents your data structure then your data stucture is incorrect. You should use a separate table to store your item scans and define a one-to-many rel.ship between your items table and your item scans table. You really don't want to store scans per date in separate tables.

Comment: As @Rene said, correct the data structure then use a nested TOP N query.

Comment: [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select [Part Number], [Rack Number], [Row Number], Max([Date Scanned]) As [Last Scanned]
From 
    (Select [Part Number], [Rack Number], [Row Number], [Date Scanned]
    From Table1
    Union
    Select [Part Number], [Rack Number], [Row Number], [Date Scanned]
    From Table2)
Group By
    [Part Number], [Rack Number], [Row Number]
```